# How do I use 深深 in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

I recently came across a sentence with 深深感动 in it. Can 深深 be an adverb without 地？
For example:
让顾客和所有参与者都深深感动

Comment: Your example means the same with/out 地.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 深深 as an adverb without 地

From my answer to this [question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/29475/when-should-i-use-%E5%9C%B0-on-an-adjective-and-when-not-as-an-use-for-adverb-and-why-d)

- Adverb with 地 emphasizes the 'manner of the action'. For example '大力地打'
- Adverb without 地 focuses on the verb itself, with the adverb as an equal-weighted complement. For example '大力打'
- A single character adverb doesn't usually use 地. For example '痛打'，'狠批' (never '痛地打'，'狠地批')

Answer (score 1):

figure out the difference between 的，地，得（all are pronounce de but with different tone)

they are fixed expressions.
chinese adj + 的 + noun.
adj + 地 + verb.
adj + 得 + degree verb.

so in this case, 深深的 is an adjective, 深深地 is an adverb.
打 means to hit which is a verb, so 用力地打 is to hit hard.
and you can say 用力打 without 地 for it is a fixed expression.

for those words/phrases can either be a verb or an adjective, you could still speak without 的/地 in most cases ‘cause we can figure out whether it is an adv + verb phrase or an adj + noun phrase according to the context.

take 打击, which means blow, for example

此次行动 对 敌人 造成了 沉重(的)打击。=> this action has made a great blow on the enemies.
此次行动 沉重(地)打击了 敌人。=> this action greatly hit the enemies.